# How can I store different error interface implementations together and then use them for type comparison in Go?

Tags: pointers, go, error-handling, interface

I'm trying to write a table test in go where the test cases will result in different errors. I then want to check if the type of the error matches a an error type defined in the test case, using `errors.As()`. Each test case is defined by a struct, so there needs to be a type in the struct that can hold any implementation of the interface `error`, which is then also to verify that the correct type was returned in the test.

I have tried defining the struct as follows

```
type testCase struct {
        testInput string
        expectedError error
}
```

I also have a number of custom errors that implement the `error` interface, lets say one is called `myCustomError`

I then declare a variable of that struct like this:

```
mTest := testCase{
        testInput: "some failing string",
        expectedError: myCustomError{},
}
```

if I then do the test like this...

```
err := someFunc(mTest.testInput)
if errors.As(err, &mTest.expectedError) {
        // test have succeeded
}
```

... the if statement will always return `true`, regardless of which of my custom error types is returned.

I made a minimal example if this behavior on the Go Playground here: https://play.golang.org/p/uMdbMvfcdQi

In the playground example, I expect the string "matching myError1" to be printed twice, but instead it also matches `myError2` when the value is stored as a plain `error` before it is used to check the type of the variable err.
Is is even possible to do something like this?

Comment: Here I think you want to use `errors.Is`, not `errors.As`

Comment: @yazgazan is correct, `Is` is what you want. (https://play.golang.org/p/5LdhUUaZxCd) *"`As` unwraps its first argument sequentially looking for an error that can be assigned to its second argument, which must be a pointer. If it succeeds, it performs the assignment and returns true."*

Comment: @yazgazan This will not work if the returned error has some kind of attributes, which unfortunately they have in my real case (see https://play.golang.org/p/JIsNFJ364te)  They may also be wrapped in some other error. I omitted this from the question to make it minimal. If you have some idea on solving that I would be glad to hear it, otherwise post this as an answer and I will mark it as solved as it answers the actual question.

Comment: You can implement the `Is(error) bool` method so that `Is` works for your custom types: https://golang.org/pkg/errors/#Is.

Comment: If you are not in control of these custom error types, then the only solution that comes to mind is using reflection ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store a pointer to the target value in the test case.

```
type testCase struct {
    testInput string
    expectedError interface{}
}

mTest := testCase{
    testInput: "some failing string",
    expectedError: &myCustomError{},
}

err := someFunc(mTest.testInput)
if errors.As(err, mTest.expectedError) {
    // test have succeeded
}
```

Minimal example: https://play.golang.org/p/igJy9L_ui73